# Error while installing Sitecore in docker

Tags: jss, installation, docker, nextjs, container

I am trying to setup `Sitecore 10.3` with `docker containers`.
While trying to run the `.\up.ps1`, I am facing below error with the certificate while building the containers:

[image]

[image]

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; nuget restore -Verbosity quiet' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'solution' failed to build : Build failed
C:\sitecore\jss\docker\jssdoc\up.ps1 : Container build failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1
```

I have verified and the pem files are getting created.
I also set the environment variable as mentioned here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/210/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--configuring-sitecore-ca-certificates-for-node-js.html

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141765/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-error-while-installing-sitecore-in-docker).

Comment: I had Zscaler acting as the MITM causing the certificate issue. I got it resolved by importing the certificate to the container. This helped:
https://vincent-lui.medium.com/running-sitecore-in-docker-containers-an-enterprise-environment-b4c1d469b423

Answer (score 0):

Upload the valid certificates in `traefik` folder and change the path in `certs_config.yaml` file.

The path of certificates is shown below,

[image]